# How do I go to a webpage, wait for it to completely load, then perform some function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I tried Google Sheets XMLImport but the page I'm trying to load (https://bonanzasatrangi.com/products/hv1bn223p6-ochre) sends data dynamically and so I can't get the 'src' links of the images shown on the page.

Side question - is there a more efficient way to fetch the images from this page?

Answer (score -1):

You could try making a Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey script. It's a browser extension that allows you to run custom Javascript on specific websites.